# Google Places [Detail] API Categories not Returning Same Value as on Webpage

Tags: web-services, google-maps, web-scraping, google-places-api

I'd like to understand how or if it is possible to retrieve the same business category value via the Google Places API as the one used next to the place listing in Google search results. While the API does return a list of business categories and much other information beside, the value used on their search results page is **(a)** singular and **(b)** often in much better definition than those returned in the API response.  Examples as follows; any advice as to its availability much appreciated.

---

**Name:**  `Sydney Showboats`

---

**Google Search**

Url:  https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Sydney+Showboats

Response Category:

`Cruise agency`

---

**Google Places API:**

Url:  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Response Categories:

`["travel_agency",
  "restaurant",
  "food",
  "point_of_interest",
  "establishment"
 ]`

**NB**: The same is also true for the response from the **Google Places Detail API**.

---

How can I retrieve the finer, single term `Cruise agency` rather than the higher-level list of categories returned via the API?

Comment: maybe this "finer term" is the first term on the list. Run multiple test to find out and tell me

Answer (score -1):

I'm still experimenting with all the API calls, but I switched from nearby search to Text Search (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search).

Text Search, with query param, started showing me results that matched what was on maps.google.com.

> query — The text string on which to search, for example: "restaurant".
>   The Google Places service will return candidate matches based on this
>   string and order the results based on their perceived relevance. This
>   parameter becomes optional if the type parameter is also used in the
>   search request.

Comment: Thanks so much; sadly when I use this in my test cases it still returns the really brutal high-level category terms rather than the nice, nuanced ones I suspect they save for [human] users of their webpage.

Comment: @afair I should have mentioned that i'm also using location (lat/lng) in my search and the radius is around 1500m.  I'm sure your doing that as well, but wanted to add this to the thread.